# Matching Matrix sizes for matrix math

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to perform matrix math using numpy. I have what I expect to be a 2x2x401 matrix that I am trying to add to an identity matrix using `np.add()`. In code, I have tried:

```
result = []
self.data = x #where x is a 2x2x401 np array
z_sqrt = np.identity(2)
for x in range(401):
    result.append(np.add(z_sqrt,self.data[:][:][x]))
    #if the above gives me errors because of how I'm assigning it, I'm not there yet
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (2,401)
```

Comment: Can you show your intent in a python for loop?  I'm not sure what result you're expecting to get. Also, please make the example minimal. It will be much easier to show if the one axis didn't have 400+ elements

Comment: @MadPhysicist what do you mean by showing my intent in a python loop?

Comment: It's unclear what result you are expecting to get. Often with this sort of question, people will write out the nested for loop that implements what they expect, to avoid any possible ambiguity. I would then show you how to vectorize the loop.

Comment: `[:]` does nothing.  If you want to iterate on the last dimension of the 3d array use`data[:, :, x]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following which might help,

```
result = x + np.atleast_3d(np.identity(2))
```

where `x` is your (2,2,401) array. The above should directly work on the whole array without using the for loop so you get `result` of shape (2,2,401) in a one-liner. Alternatively you can also try the below,

```
result = x + (np.identity(2)[:,:,np.newaxis])
```

Comment: when you say without using a loop, you don't mean the for loop that I am using to loop 401 times, do you?

Comment: Yes I mean the for loop you are using in your example, (`for x in range(401)...`). The above solutions should directly give you the `result` array. I have edited the answer for more clarity

Comment: Hmm, I haven't considered including the third axis in my matrix calculations. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, please also don't forget to upvote the answer :)